# css display:table max-witdh with firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm looking to use display:table, but I have a problem only with firefox.
Firefox doesn't want to take the value of max-width

```
<div class="container" style = "display: table;width: 600px;max-width: 600px;">
<div class="column" style="display: table-cell; background-color:blue;"><img src="http://www.supportduweb.com/ftp/ybouane/scripts_astuces/photoshop/logo_google/img_final.png" style="max-width:100%;"></div>
<div class="column" style="display: table-cell; background-color:green;"><img src="http://www.supportduweb.com/ftp/ybouane/scripts_astuces/photoshop/logo_google/img_final.png" style="max-width:100%;"></div>
<div class="column" style="display: table-cell; background-color:red;"><img src="http://www.gizmodo.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/yahoo1.png" style="max-width:100%;"></div>
```

If I put table-layout: fixed; on the container the max-width is ok but all column have the same width. How to make this with table-layout: auto;

Tks in advance for your help.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/k9TbE/1/